# Why is my ProxyPass and uWSGI not connecting?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, uwsgi, mod-proxy

I am trying to get a python environment live for a Django project and it's fighting me. I have installed `mod_proxy_uwsgi` through EasyApache4 (`mod_proxy` was already on). I have added the following include in the Apache include editor under pre-virtual host (Versioned):

```
include /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/user/domain/proxy.conf
```

with the following content:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/"  "unix://localhost/var/run/swerth_django.sock"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "unix://localhost/var/run/swerth_django.sock"
```

I have used YUM installer to install uWSGI and run using a .ini file (command:`uwsgi --ini php.ini`) with the following content which is executing fine so far (no error messages):

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/swerth/public_html/mysite
module=mysite.wsgi:application
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
master=True
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
socket=127.0.0.1:49152
processes=5
harakiri=20
post-buffering=1
max-requests=5000
vacuum=True
home=/home/swerth/public_html/Swerth.VirtualEnv
```

Despite all this, it's still not working. My Django project still isn't serving. I have a sneaky suspicion that there's something I don't understand about these systems and reverse proxying. Is there something I'm missing or messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so turns out I was adding my Include function under the versioned part of the includes editor and it needed to be added under the global one because of how the includes editor adds the files to the main httpd.conf file (versioned wasn't being included into the main httpd.conf for some reason)